# General formula of a sequence $a_{n+1} = 2a_n + 1/a_n$

Tags: recurrence-relations

What is the exact formula for $a_n$ in the sequence $a_{n+1} = 2a_n + 1/a_n, a_1=1$?
I discovered that there are no elementary answers, but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: what is the first term?

Comment: The first term is one. I forgot to add that. Thank you.

Comment: I don't get it. You know in advance that no nice closed form exists, and you are asking for a closed form?

Comment: maybe he meant that he knows there is no very simple way to get the closed formula.

Comment: I am asking for the equation for $a_n$.  Calculus is allowed so its not a closed form.

Comment: There's a closed form don't worry ^^

Comment: I've just checked that answer it seems to be wrong :/

Comment: Yup, the most upvoted answer there is wrong,